# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined - Laravel 5.5 + Laravel Mix

Tags: php, jquery, webpack, laravel-5.5, laravel-mix

I recently check out my project from SVN. I ran into "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" where ever I have used "$" ie; Jquery. I am using laravel mixer to combine the JS and CSS Files.

This is my **bootstrap.js**

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.tooltip = require('tooltip.js');



try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js');
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}


window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';



let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

//Moment JS
window.moment = require('moment');
//Collect JS
window.collect = require('collect.js');
//Clipboard JS
window.ClipboardJS = require('clipboard');
//Import Toster
window.toastr = require('toastr');
//Swaet Alert
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

window.swal = Swal;
//Owl Carousel
window.owlCarousel =  require('owl.carousel');
//JS Cookie
window.Cookies = require('js-cookie');
//Image Zoom
require('ez-plus');
```

This is my **webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps()
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

My Laravel Version: 5.5.40
laravel-mix Version: 1.7.2

Comment: This is happening because of wrong order or JS files being appended one after another. As you have given path to JS folder, the files in that folder will be in alphabetic order and so the sequence in the minified JS file.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I have not modified the bootstrap.js file.I have kept as it was.

Comment: So if your custom Jquery code which uses `$` from `jquery.min.js` file and it is appended to the minified file before jquery file got added, then obviously it is not going to get reference of `$`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

Remove the defer from the `app.js` script tag and change `window.$ = window.jquery =` to `global.$ = global.jquery =`

Weather or not this is the correct way to do it, this has worked for me.

**laravel 5.7**